# phone:webbrowser does not open PDF files (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have build an app with a webbrowser in it. It's working fine but when I try to navigate to an adress like bla.**pdf** the webbrowser shows nothing.
I solved this problem with automatically open the Internet Explorer if the adress is linking to a pdf file.

Is there a better solution? I want to open that PDF file in my own app and I dont want to open the Internet Explorer everytime. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think there is built in support for PDF files in the OS currently.

Comment: I found this link regarding Windows Store apps. I think it's the same for WP8: They have disabled that feature as a safty precaution. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN3

Comment: Can you share the code how you automatically open the IE when pdf or docs are stored in the isolatedstoreage? I am too trying to do the same thing and its not working.

Comment: I dont work with the isolatedstorage. It's just a Launcherapp which launches a mobile website. I just check if the next clicked link is a pdf document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a locally downloaded PDF that is in Isolated Storage you can launch the PDF Reader application (or any other applications registered to open PDF files) using `LaunchFileAsync`.

```
 private async void LaunchFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs rea)
 {

    // Access isolated storage.
    StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    // Access the PDF.
    StorageFile pdfFile = await local.GetFileAsync("file1.pdf");

    // Launch the bug query file.
    Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdfFile);
}
```

(adapted from [MSDN, see section on "launching a file"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)).

If it's a remote URL then you can use `LaunchUriAsync` (which will use IE to download the file first).

You will need to try this on a device with the PDF Reader application installed - it won't work on the Emulator.

Comment: This seems to work only once.  If I click another item in my list then the browser get stuck on "Tap to Open".  The url is online and is different every time I click the list item, this eliminates chaching

Answer (score 0):

You should read following article if you are not familiar with Async: MSDN Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await

I couldn't test my app because my WP8 Phone is currently not available and I can't install an PDF reader on the emulator.

Call following method to start the download

```
WebClient pdfDownloader = null;
string LastFileName = ""; //To save the filename of the last created pdf

private void StartPDFDownload(string URL)
{
    pdfDownloader = new WebClient(); //prevents that the OpenReadCompleted-Event is     called multiple times
    pdfDownloader.OpenReadCompleted += DownloadPDF; //Create an event handler
    pdfDownloader.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(URL)); //Start to read the website
}

async void DownloadPDF(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length]; //Gets the byte length of the pdf file
    await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //Waits until the rad is completed (Async doesn't block the GUI Thread)

    using (IsolatedStorageFile ISFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        try
        {
            LastFileName = "tempPDF" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".pdf";
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream ISFileStream = ISFile.CreateFile(LastFileName))
            {
                await ISFileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.HResult,
            ex.Source, MessageBoxButton.OK);
        //Catch errors regarding the creation of file
        }
     }    
    OpenPDFFile();
}

private async void OpenPDFFile()
{
    StorageFolder ISFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    try
    {
        IStorageFile ISFile = await ISFolder.GetFileAsync(LastFileName);
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(ISFile);
        //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //Catch unknown errors while getting the file
    //or opening the app to display it
    }
}
```

To call these methods from your WebBrowser-Control you need to catch the navigating event.

```
YourWebBrowserControl.Navigating += YourWebBrowserControl_Navigating;

void YourWebBrowserControl_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Uri.AbsolutPath.EndsWith("pdf"))
    {
        StartPDFDownload(e.Uri.ToString());
    }
}
```

Don't forget that you'll have to delete the files created someday.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to open a PDF from a WebControl:

```
void MyWebBrowserControl_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Uri.AbsolutPath.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf"))
    {
        var success = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(e.Uri);
    }
}
```